# Binding Vue data attribute values in template when using Vueify render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, browserify

I'm new to Vue and am having issues with the values in the `data` attribute binding to the placeholders in my Vueify template. I'm sure this is a simple lack of understanding, but any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Browserify to run the Vueify transformation on my .vue files.

This is my current setup:

```js
    new Vue({
        el: '#clip-slides',
        render : function(createElement){
            var template = require('./clips.vue');
            return createElement(template);
        },
        data : {
            'testValue' : 'I am a test value!'
        }
    });
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        {{testValue}}
    </div>
</template>
```

The placeholder `testValue` in the template gets replaced with an empty string.

What do I need to do to properly provide my "data" options to my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as a property.

**Clips.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
      {{testValue}}
    </div>
</template>

<<script>
export default {
  props: ['testValue']
}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render(h){
    let template = require("./Clips.vue")
    return h(template, {props:{testValue: this.testValue}})
  },
  data:{
    testValue: "hello world!"
  }
})
```

Working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/myqp8y7w6p).

Comment: In what situations do you use props vs data?

Comment: @RyanGriffith Properties are essentially the interface to the component. When you want to pass data from parent to child, you pass the data via properties. If the component changes that data, you typically emit the new value. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

Comment: Thanks @Bert, I was able to get my example I provided here running using this method, however this example was exactly that, just an example. I am not sure how I would apply this to my actual situation in which I use components (not built by me) inside my template that require attributes in the `data` property defined. How would I pass that using props? Specifically I'm trying to use: https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/examples/

Comment: @RyanGriffith I don't see that you need to set any data at all there. Looks like its just using slots.

Comment: here is a specific example: https://jsfiddle.net/Wlada/stsao0e1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=stsao0e1

Comment: Thanks @Bert. I was able to adapt your example to my use case.